# Audio player doesn't play the mp3 discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The audio player doesn't play anything in the voice channel. There is only the green ring around the profile but no sound. Does anyone know why? I'm using discord.js v13

```
const { Client, Intents, discord } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({  intents: [ Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES ]});
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { createAudioPlayer, AudioPlayerStatus, createAudioResource } = require('@discordjs/voice');

client.on("message", message => {
if(message.content.startsWith("!play")){

const channel = message.member.voice.channel


  const player = createAudioPlayer();
  player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Playing, () => {
    message.channel.send("Now playing")
  })
  player.on("error", error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
  const resource = createAudioResource('./music.mp3');

  player.play(resource)

  const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
    guildId: message.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
  });

  const subscription = connection.subscribe(player)
  if(subscription){
    setTimeout(() => {
     subscription.unsubscribe()
    }, 15_000)
  }


}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine whats causing the problem is that you need to install `ffmpeg-static` ( you can find the relating post from the discord.js documentation [here](https://discordjs.guide/voice/#barebones) ). ffmpeg is used for converting mp3 files to something your discord bot can play. You should also have `@discordjs/voice` and `discord.js` but by the looks of it you have.

Please let me know if installing ffmpeg-static solves your problem